# Django decorator unresolved reference

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I created a decorator to return JSON from a view, however when using it ontop of the method I am getting an unresolved reference.

This is the decorator:

```
def json_response(func):
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')

    return decorator
```

And this is how I am trying to use it:

```
@json_response
def get_json(request, param1, param2):
    return { 'param1': param1, 'param2': param2 }
```

I am getting an unresolver reference when using the decorator, in the `@json_response` line.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Django 1.4.

Comment: What does "I am getting an unresolved reference" mean? Where are you "getting" it? Exactly what error do you see? Also, why are you using a version of Django that is completely unsupported?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified where I was getting the error. It's at the `@json_response'  line. It's not up to me what version of Django is to be used.

Comment: But "unresolved reference" is not a Python error. Is this some kind of IDE warning? Do you get a real error when you run the code? Have you actually imported the decorator into the file where you are using it?

Comment: Oh it's not a Python error? Well my IDE (PyCharm) marks it as an error. And my console says it IS an error: `NameError: name 'json_response' is not defined`. The decorator is in the same file I am using it.

Comment: Right, so that was what I wanted you to tell me in the first place: the actual error you see. So where is it defined in relation to where you use it? Maybe you should show the full file.

Comment: It's defined after it's being used. Could this be it?

Comment: OK that was it, I am stupid. Getting used to Python...

Comment: Yes. Note that this happens because decorator definitions (like anything at module level) are called at import time, not when the function itself is called.